# HTML/JS/ASP: Check If User Exists - SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is working, but the `COUNT(*)` always returns `-1`. I am trying to check if a user exists in my HTML/JS/ASP code. I don't think I am converting the value correctly, but I am not certain. The code I am focused on is:

```
@{
var userCheck = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USR WHERE EMAIL = @email1";
var rowCount = db.Execute(userCheck);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(rowCount.ToString());
}
```

My Javascript code is: `var error = "";` and `error += @temp;`. I don't understand why it is always returning negative one. Please assist! `:-)`

Here is my full code for `@ { }`

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Register";
    var minPass = 2;
    var maxPass = 100;
    var email1 = "";
    var pass1 = "";
    var db = Database.Open("Resume");
    var userCheck = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USR WHERE EMAIL = @email1";
    var userInsert = "INSERT INTO USR (EMAIL, PSWD) VALUES (@0, @1)";
    var rowCount = db.Execute(userCheck);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(rowCount.ToString());


    if(IsPost) {
        email1 = Request.Form["email1"];
        pass1 = Request.Form["pass1"];
        db.Execute(userInsert, email1, pass1);
        Response.Redirect("~/Default");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are using dapper or ado.net and you are not passing parameter @email1

Comment: let me update to my full code

Comment: There is no JavaScript in the question.

Comment: First Are using dapper,Second where are you passing value of parameter @email1 ?

Comment: He isn't passing a parameter value.  The parameters should be the second argument to `db.Execute()`.  His second invocation of `db.Execute()` does include the parameters.

Comment: both queries are parameterized, He is not passing parameter in first query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to apologize for having asked such a stupid question - my approach was entirely wrong. After spending hours upon hours, I have formulated a solution: websecurity.

Below is a working solution for myself. Be sure to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ResumeLink", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);`

```
@{ 
    var username = "";
    var password = "";
    var confirmPassword = "";
    var regMsg = "";
    var minPass = 2;
    var maxPass = 5;


    if (!IsPost) {
    if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
        regMsg = String.Format("You are already logged in. (User name: {0})", WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
        }
    }

    if (IsPost){
    WebSecurity.Logout();    
    username = Request["username"];
    password = Request["password"];
    confirmPassword = Request["confirmPassword"];

    try {
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(username);
    } catch {
        regMsg += "Invalid email format.";
    }

    //Validation.Add("username", Validator.Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$", regMsg += "Invalid email format."));
    if (password != confirmPassword) {regMsg += "</br>Passwords don't match.";}
    if (WebSecurity.UserExists(username)) {regMsg += String.Format("</br>User '{0}' already exists.", username);}
    if (password.Length < minPass || password.Length > maxPass) {regMsg += "</br>Password doesn't meet length requirement.";}
    if (regMsg == "") {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username,password,null,false);
        regMsg = String.Format("{0} created.", username);
        Response.Write("Registration Successful!");
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.cshtml");
        }
    }
}

<style>header {visibility: hidden;}</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                @if(regMsg != ""){
                    <span class="errorMessage">@Html.Raw(regMsg)</span>
                }
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="username">Email Address:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value='@Request["username"]' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password @minPass-@maxPass Characters:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
            </p>   
            <p>
                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" value="" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:location.href='Default.cshtml'" />
            </p>   
            <p>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a reputation high enough to comment but what the others said is correct. You need to parameterize your first query. Check out the SqlCommand AddWithParameter method to do that.

I also saw another issue in your code. You have the rowCount variable which will store an integer that contains the amount of users in the database with a specific email, but you need to do some logic with that before you insert another user into the database.